# Make [international] a synonym of [internationalization]

Tags: support, meta, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

NOTE: On 2018-10-09 a tag excerpt and wiki were added to [international](/questions/tagged/international)

UPDATE: On 2018-10-22 [international](/questions/tagged/international) was renamed as [international-sites](/questions/tagged/international-sites)

---

- [international](/questions/tagged/international) currently has two questions but no wiki.
- [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization) has fifty questions and has a wiki.

The above will help people interested on international Stack Exchange sites like es.so, pt.so, ru.so and ja.so to follow the topics related to that sites.

NOTES:

[international](/questions/tagged/international) was proposed by a *valued associate* on [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691). I already give feedback about it on [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315461/289691). I posted ta proposal for a tag for the new communication processes questions about Stack Overflow International sites on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315479/289691).

Comment: Its probably easiest to just retag the international to internationalization manually so long as they mean the same thing

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh On "normal circunstancies" I had being proceeded directly to do that. I edited my question to add some context about this request.

Comment: [Ok, let's start the vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/internationalization/synonyms)!

Comment: I retagged the existing uses, but those were all rolled back by another employee.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog I'm wondering if [tag:international] should have a icon like the SO sponsored tags.

Answer (score 6):

Initial-substring synonyms are at best pointless.  If we only have [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization), then somebody starting to type "internat" will see it as an auto-completion.  If that's what the poster meant, great -- select it and you're done.  A synonym does not make this any smoother.

But in this case it sounds like they're different tags.  "Internationalization" is a technical term, so I'd expect to see questions about *how to do* internationalization (tools, libraries, policies, etc).  The tag that @JuanM created is (I think) for *discussions that should be held in all SE-relevant languages*.  That's different.  I don't think "international" is a good name for that tag because it's (demonstrably) unclear, but I don't have a good counter-proposal.

Comment: That's right, at this time we have two tags that start with `international`. At this time on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691 there are suggestions for the tag to be used for the new communication processes between the communities of sites that have a fully localized UI ([es.so], [pt.so], [ja.so], [ru.so] and [russian.se])  and "the company".

Comment: @Rubén so you agree they're different tags?  If so, then making a synonym would break things; instead we want two (clearly-named) tags, it sounds like.

Comment: I agree that we have two tags but I don't think that creating this synonym will break anything because the questions that use [tag:international] should be using [tag:internationalization]. By the way, Juan M proposed the synonym so it looks that he hasn't any problem with the synonym creation.

Comment: @Rubén in that case the tags should be merged.  Having a synonym doesn't help anything, for the reason I gave in my first paragraph.

Comment: What is the difference between merge and creating a synonym for this specific case? From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/289691 "All good tag synonyms should eventually be merged"

Comment: @Rubén a merge says "take all the questions that are tagged X and tag them Y instead".  A synonym says "let X and Y both be visible as tags, but send them all to the Y bucket".  Synonyms are intended for cases where there's different vocabulary to talk about the same thing, such as "moving-questions" and "migration" or "child-meta" and "per-site-meta" (the former are synonyms of the latter).

Comment: I still think that a synomym is required as [tag:international] was created even when [tag:internationalization] already existed.