# Welcome Stack Overflow Valued Associate #599, Catherine Kuck AKA Catija!

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

We're extremely pleased to announce that Catherine Kuck (most of you know her as [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)) started yesterday on our Community Growth team as a Community Manager. As soon as she's completed a small mountain of paperwork, she's going to be spending the bulk of her time doing ... *pretty much exactly what she's been doing for a while now*, which is supporting users across the network while working with other moderators.

Catherine found her start in [casting](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3795368/) after graduating with a film degree, but she quickly found that she didn't care for the long and odd hours that the job required. She first discovered Stack Exchange in 2014 when she wandered into [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com), then discovered [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) and unwittingly began her journey into her ultimate *role* (I kill me, I really do) as a strong leader on our network. After she applied, we thought it would be nice if she received a paycheck for what she's currently doing, she didn't disagree.

In her spare time, Catija likes crochet, watching movies, and can [pipe a pretty awesome hat with icing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304644/50049). When her toddler let her get stuff done, she worked with a pretty amazing team of moderators on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) to make one of our most controversial sites a success.

Catija is going to be working with Juan M spending *most* of her time [helping Stack Exchange grow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network) and remain a safe place for people to get answers to their questions, while lending some of her hard-earned expertise in helping folks be civil to our welcome wagon initiatives.

Please join us in congratulating Cat in her new role! Questions about the stuff she's going to be working on, or questions in general? Let us know, she and our CM team will answer 'em! If you don't know how *catija* is pronounced, now would be a great time to ask.

Comment: Catija is a regular in the Tavern on the Meta and her interactions and style are a prime example of how to lead a community to greener pastures. I'm confident you've added extra quality on top of the amazing people you already have around. Congratulations Catija. You'll do fine.

Comment: The others have already said Congratulations, I'd like to say Thank you! ... She's been of great help in both TL and the team (*cough* our rivalry there still stands :p). Hope that she remains as active as she was before!

Comment: Congratulations to Catija!!  She was one of the first people I met on SE and has always been super helpful and knowledgeable in all things SE.  She is the only other girl in The Screening Room with me to help keep those boys in line. lol.  I'm super happy for you, Catija!!  Love ya, babe :)

Comment: How is _catija_ pronounced?

Comment: @JonSchneider ka-tee-ya /kəˈtiʤə/

Comment: @Braiam Actually,according to her bio, it's kat-ya (slight difference, but it matters, I think).

Comment: @Braiam Using "y" to represent /ʤ/ is confusing ...

Comment: @Ash mmm... the j doesn't sound? That's weird.

Comment: Wait, where is her diamond? ;)

Comment: @Shadow "*as soon as she's completed a small mountain of paperwork*"

Comment: @Sonic turns out it's not the case. :)

Comment: @Tim where did the number 599 come from?

Comment: This is really exciting!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Including the founders, 599th employee who has brought value to Stack Overflow (aka 599th employee).

Comment: Was she called Catherine DeMartino in the past?

Comment: So I guess that means IPS is losing her as a community mod?

Comment: Correct, @T.E.D. The team there is already well-staffed, but we'll be happy to appoint a replacement if/when the need arises.

Comment: I wonder how she found the time for her contribution before getting hired here

Comment: @Ooker She worked in a job where she had a copious amount of spare time to contribute.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Yes, that was her name before she got married.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog and may I know what that job is?

Comment: @Ooker Go ask her in the Tavern if you want to know.

Comment: Very Nice! can we have a blog for this?

Comment: Btw, what is "welcome wagon initiatives"?

Comment: @Pandya [Welcome Wagon mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312041/278659). Basically, the new stuff that's being rolled out about being welcoming and inclusive.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Do employees who didn't end up bringing any value to Stack Overflow get their numbers re-used then? :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's purely conjectural; either there haven't been any, or they have been expunged from public records.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Eradicated from the timeline perhaps

Comment: @T.E.D. For what it's worth, when we got two more mods earlier this year, it was a big help. We have four even without Catija, and it looks like we'll be fine for now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - all your causality are belong to us...

Comment: @BobJarvis: Main flux capacitor turn on

Comment: Congratulations @Catija!

Comment: I can see many answers with very little content and getting upvotes which should have been comments instead. I think your work start from this thread only. @Catija  :P By the way Congratulations, do your best. :)

Comment: Congratulations @Catija. On a side note I would hate to be employee #666

Answer (score 235, accepted):

It's such an amazing honor for me to join Stack Overflow and the Community Team. I've long respected their work and I look forward to sticking my oar into things, figuring out what needs help, and being there to *at least* listen, but hopefully actually act.

I know that the Network is a complicated place with a varied collection of needs and that what works for one site may not work for all of them (or any of the others). Taking time to get to know the moderators and users on the sites I'm not already familiar with is a priority for me and I'm looking forward to figuring out what sites need in order to do their thing better.

I'm really excited to be a part of Juan M's team as it really focuses on what I think makes these sites one of the best places on the web - the community of users who come together with the goal of helping others find the answers they need to the problems they face. We want to help the sites do this better - whether you get tons of questions per day or less than 1 - [so speak up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network). We can't guarantee that we can solve all of your problems but we need to know what they are so that we can try.

I'm also a huge proponent of the welcome wagon initiative. I understand that it's not universally accepted. It's difficult for me to look in the mirror and see that my actions haven't always been perfect. I have some in my past that, looking back on, I would have done differently, even if that meant not engaging at all. I've struggled with never-ending flows of low quality questions on the sites I've used and recognize that taking some of the weight off of the first-line users and making first-time users more successful from the start is just as important as asking everyone to put a bit more thought into the user interactions they're having here. I feel that both sides of this are being addressed and I look forward to seeing how things can improve for both groups.

Thank you to the Team and everyone else for the welcome and to the users of the network for being here and wanting more from this great platform.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have a question. I don't see cake. Where is the cake?

Comment: The cake is a lie. Didn't I mention that she got started on Gaming?

Comment: Now that you're gone, can I continue my dominance in *the* arena? :D

Comment: congratulations....!!!!

Comment: Happy Puppy... Happy Puppy! *woof woof*!

Comment: Where's your diamond? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor ... Locked in Shog's desk.

Comment: Congrats! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Ya, ya, ya, get back to work traitor :P

Comment: @Randal'Thor Dug them out. :D

Comment: @Randal'Thor the diamond is now Unlocked :D

Comment: We've crossed paths before.  I'm pleasantly surprised to see you take this position.  Congratulations!  You'll be a valuable asset to the team.

Comment: Congrats @Catija :o) Not that I didn't know you were coming, but glad I can officially say it now. You will make a great addition to the team!

Comment: Two questions. #1 do CMs get a welcome box upon receiving the position? #2 What is in the box?

Comment: @David #1 Yes. #2 Marsellus Wallace's Soul.

Comment: !

Comment: Doesn't 'low quality' have a hyphen? [I think it does.](http://www.marywood.edu/marketing/brand/editorial-guide/hyphenation.html) Less than 6 chars or I would edit it myself, yes I am that picky.

Comment: Congratulations Catija! Best of luck with your new role

Comment: Congratulations for your new role, @Catija. Lessons learned from your experience in multiple communities with different backgrounds, even people sometimes disagree with your decisions. We wish you good luck from today.

Comment: Congratulations and good luck, Catija! Not that you'll need it; having worked with you in your mod days, I am absolutely sure that you'll do a great job.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I like your name :3 - Congratz Catija!

Comment: @Pandya: How did you write that?

Comment: @Pops - Of course, but you'll always have a special place in our hearts :)

Comment: Welcome Ma'am! Hope you'll have great moments/times here ...:]

Comment: Thanks so much @Pops ! You're definitely missed.

Comment: Juan M's team? Do you have a link?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's in the question. :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network

Comment: *dang nabbit* my stupid eyeballs missed it

Comment: I've seen your posts all over Movies & TV, and to be honest I always thought you were a guy.  :oD  I guess I should pay closer attention.  Congrats on your new role.

Comment: As a random user, the fact of recognizing your name for having seen that your presence was always positive wherever you were makes me sure that this has been an excellent decision. Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: CONGRATS CATIJA!  I've just found out that you're in Austin, too! :D

Answer (score 62):

## Congratulations!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Queue Cliff Richard?

Comment: inb4 smoke detector thinks your posts contains too many punctuation marks :)

Comment: @Dragonrage And "repeating characters in answer" :P

Answer (score 40):

@Catija Congratulations!!!!

Your sincere efforts deserve this achievement. All the best for your future!!

[image: Gif of Professor Snape, of *Harry Potter* fame, clapping and looking shiftily]

Comment: Ow, animated gif.

Comment: But if he stops clapping those candles will fall down and that could start a fire.

Comment: @TimPost yeah, I get that -- it's just that animated images are *really* distracting when trying to read any other part of the page...

Comment: It is tempting me to clap ;)

Comment: @TimPost: And then he'll just use some magic to put it out.  You need to think fourth dimensionally. ;)

Answer (score 25):

Congratulations, and I'd say, excellent choice - especially with what they've been talking about with the new team

Answer (score 22):

*Note: I rewrote this answer from scratch to be more constructive. Meta-commentary about the previous version is towards the end.*

---

Congratulations to Catija on joining the Stack Overflow team.

While I have crossed swords with her in the past a number of times, I look forward to working with her more constructively to address issues. In particular, I hope we would be able to deal with criticism and have difficult conversations without ending up with "drop the discussion" or "N people agree/disagree with you". :-)

---

*I would have probably written the above answer to start with if dissenting comments on another answer had not been removed. Unfortunately, Catija bore the brunt of my displeasure with an action that she had nothing to do with. While nothing I say or do will make up for ruining her first day at work, I express my regret and apologize to Catija and everyone else whose day was ruined.*

Comment: I appreciate your update, almost free of passive agression now.

Answer (score 21):

I must admit, for a long time I was skeptical about this whole Welcome Wagon stuff. I still am, but  now with Catija on board I am a lot less skeptical and more optimistic it might actually work.

I'm also glad she's the first Valued Associate to be announced on Meta, all the rest have been announced [in the blog](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:blog.stackexchange.com+%22Valued+Associate%22) before.

So... congrats and keep doing what you do! :)

Answer (score 14):

I too want to congratulate you on your new position. (The meta diamond looks good on you.)

Your dedication to SE is profound. There are many examples where you worked through things and helped ISP along. You will be a great asset to the whole SE community.

Don't get too bogged down. The haters are going to hate, and nothing you do will change that. Keep your head on and your heart light, just brush it off. You will do great things.

Answer (score 14):

```js
// Click "Congratulations!" to play animation

$(function() {
  var numberOfStars = 150;

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
    $('.congrats').append('<div class="blob fa fa-star ' + i + '"></div>');
  }

  animateText();

  animateBlobs();
});

$('.congrats').click(function() {
  reset();

  animateText();

  animateBlobs();
});

function reset() {
  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    TweenMax.set($(this), {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1
    });
  });

  TweenMax.set($('h1'), {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    rotation: 0
  });
}

function animateText() {
  TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
    scale: 0.4,
    opacity: 0,
    rotation: 15,
    ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
  });
}

function animateBlobs() {

  var xSeed = _.random(350, 380);
  var ySeed = _.random(120, 170);

  $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
    var $blob = $(this);
    var speed = _.random(1, 5);
    var rotation = _.random(5, 100);
    var scale = _.random(0.8, 1.5);
    var x = _.random(-xSeed, xSeed);
    var y = _.random(-ySeed, ySeed);

    TweenMax.to($blob, speed, {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      opacity: 0,
      rotation: rotation,
      scale: scale,
      onStartParams: [$blob],
      onStart: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'block');
      },
      onCompleteParams: [$blob],
      onComplete: function($element) {
        $element.css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);
body {
  background: #3da1d1;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.congrats {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 140px;
  width: 550px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h1 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Chopin Script'/*, cursive*/;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.blob {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #ffcc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="congrats">
  <h1>Congratulations!</h1>
</div>
```

Ref: [JoeHastings-pen](https://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/yeeqNv)

Comment: Improvement: Warn readers that multiple 3rd party cross-site scripts are being used, unless that person owns and runs the page from cloudflare.com, then only one 3rd party cross-site script is used.

Comment: If I was a designer I'd be temped to DV this because it renders the "Congratulations!" in Comic Sans. (you linked a different font from the one you are using.)

Comment: @David Original font they wanted (Chopin Script) wasn't available from Google fonts API, so I swapped it with Great Vibes and removed the comment that someone edited so it will default to any cursive font available, which I believe is what the author wanted.

Comment: Or tried to, but the edit was rejected...

Answer (score 13):

I wouldn't exactly call IPS a success.

From my interactions with her, she's contributed to the toxicity of IPS, but also has some very well-formed answers.  I deleted my account there because her and other mods/high-rep-users created a very hostile environment for people with differing world views from their own.

Even when trying to be civil and discussing how to communicate across our differences, she and others fanned the flames at times.  Some of this may be due to the inherently polar nature of the type of questions the site receives, so the behavior is not without reason.

**That said, I wish you success in your new role, the wisdom and divine skill to herd cats, and that you can learn from past mistakes.  We all want StackOverflow to succeed, and you are now part of that.**

Comment: This answer provides a much-needed example of how someone who disagrees *strongly* with another person can still express that disagreement civilly, with hope and a level of humanity. The comments below it... Not so much. I've purged all of the comments, and advise anyone who would consider leaving a fresh one to think carefully about what they hope to accomplish first.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations and best of luck to Catija.

Stack Exchange seems to be going through some unprecedented changes, by setting some enormous and admirable goals - starting with the creation of the new Code of Conduct.  This "promotion from within" is another step in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

#### Congratulations, Catija!

When I first discovered that you'd got the job I was really pleased but certainly not surprised.

For context, I've only been a mod for about 11 months. One of the best parts about moderating on SE is that we have a real team spirit, great support and all of the existing mods (and team) are really keen to share their knowledge. Your advice, in varying locations (MSE, Chat, IPS), have helped me think about how to moderate, manage and do what I can to grow my site in new ways. Thank you for that.

I'm really excited to see what you bring to the team and I wish you all the best in your new role.

Answer (score 8):

## [Congratulations!!!!](https://media.giphy.com/media/ehhuGD0nByYxO/giphy.gif)

All the very best for your new job as Community Manager. I'm sure you will be as  successful as you are (or more than that) on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonalskills.stackexchange.com) and [Arts & Crafts](https://Crafts.Stackexchange.com) as a moderator.

I hope the diamond they gave you is [green](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37767619#37767619) ;-).

Answer (score 6):

That sucks. #599. One away from being the 600th. So sad...so...sad.

---

Just kidding :)

### Congrats!!

Answer (score 5):

### Congrats!

Wish you the best for the future.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations!  SE has made an excellent choice, and I'm sure you'll continue improving the various sites.  You've demonstrated a consistent ability to be a positive influence.  We're all lucky to have you in a more official position!

Answer (score 3):

You are one of the people I most respect on the network. You always are willing to answer a question from the newbie mod or to help out in anyway you can...

I look forward to seeing you around with the CM diamond =) My deepest congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

## CONGRATULATIONS, AND THANK YOU!

While I haven't had any specific interactions with Catija (well, maybe one), it's apparent to me that, wherever she has ever been a mod, nothing famously bad has ever happened. Since I'm not particularly active in those sites, I don't really know about the past, but I still feel like Catija has contributed *a lot* to SE being in as nice a condition as it is right now. I can't imagine what it would have been like without her amazing effort, and I know that, with her as an employee, Stack Exchange will be going only towards the best.

Seeing her history, I only want to thank her for her choice to volunteer as a member back then when she joined. I believe she has an amazing, optimistic personality, and is more than fit to work for SE. I always saw her tendency towards getting diamonds, and thought that, maybe, it was time for her to become an employee. I wasn't wrong. I also saw her being excited for becoming one; I can't describe my feelings in words, I just feel sorry in advance, when that excitement breaks down and the real exhaustion from work begins...

Overall, I believe Catija is going to live a very beautiful career, while she will still get to enjoy those unique, happy motherly moments with little Bennett that she won't be able to relive once they're over, even if she gets another child.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I will hope you  do good work

Answer (score 2):

## Congrats Catija.

We compete in the Pro term mod election of Inter personal Stack last year and she made it.
I already knew her from the Tavern and I believe she'll make a good CM. She know how to behave to different types of people and that is important to moderate such a large community.

Finally, now you can see spams and all the dirty things across the network. Enjoy it!!!

Answer (score -1):

Congratulations!!, it will be great having you as the CM.