# Does Facebook's 120 billion dollar loss in market value affect Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, advertising, business-model

With the huge loss in market valuation of Facebook -- currently a loss of 120 billion USD -- and with signals that indicate it will experience a continued, long-term decline in profits, is Stack Exchange affected by this news?  If so, how?

For example, this news article talks briefly about the ripple effects on several other tech companies:

https://www.thestreet.com/technology/ripple-effects-of-facebook-slump-already-spreading-14662653

Comment: because of market loss Facebook will be able to afford less developers => there will be less folks using Stack Overflow => less visits. Yeah I guess SE will be negatively affected

Comment: Just to be clear: Loss (or gain) in market value is based on the speculation done on a stock exchange, right? That is imaginary dollars, right?

Comment: @rene rep is also imaginary points.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, I didn't want to make that connection yet. But there is definitely a joke in there.

Comment: inb4 someone points out that all money is pretty much a consensual hallucination anyway :D

Comment: @JalapenoNachos to be clear, do you think that Stack Exchange is affiliated with Facebook, in any way?

Comment: Dunno about advertising. About other comments and answers, I am afraid they're all joking for now.

Comment: Why is this question put on hold as POB?  It's an important question that can be answered definitively.

Comment: I beg to differ it is an important question. It is POB because all we can do is speculate about the answers. Stack Overflow Inc. is privately held and therefor financed differently and foremost they are not required to publish their balance sheet, nor have they ever done so. And even if external events affects the day-to-day or long term operation, what do you expect them to answer here or how does answers here mitigate effects. Although you could argue FB and SE look somewhat familiar (they both are website with users) their business models do not match.

Comment: Why is this important? Maybe I'm missing something but why is this anything to do with SE?

Comment: @Cai ripple effects, overall trends in the online advertising space, and overall health of Stack Exchange are some examples that come to mind.

Comment: This is not important, nor answerable in any useful way. As Cai shed, why do you think there should be any connection at all?

Comment: because of market loss Facebook will be able to afford less developers => there will be increases in competitor companies and their value and thus more hiring so more folks using Stack Overflow => more visits. Yeah I guess SE will be positively affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Some tech companies who previously advertised on Facebook will inevitably switch to sites which do offer high-quality content like Stack Exchange. As long as they can make their ads [on-topic for selected Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287242/295232), they're welcome here, leading to more revenue for the company. They're already [expanding their team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313086/295232) in anticipation of this.

</jk>