# Unicorn Meta Zoo #6: Interview with Catija

Tags: discussion, podcast, unicorn-meta-zoo

Welcome to the Unicorn Meta Zoo, a podcast by members of the Stack
Exchange Community Management Team. If you want to avoid spoilers, jump
[straight to the audio](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/catija.mp3).

#### Participants

[image: Catija]
[image: Jon Ericson]

Back in May, Jon interviewed me ([Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313086/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-599-catherine-kuck-aka-catija)) while we were both in NYC for a meetup. Serendipitously, I get to share it with y'all on the one-year anniversary of my first day working for Stack Exchange. The interview was a lot of fun to do and I hope you enjoy listening to it!

#### Links

- [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/)
- [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

#### Transcript

Some users have generously volunteered to transcribe episodes on
[the podcast wiki](https://github.com/unicorn-meta-zoo/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/wiki).

#### Meta

Jon Ericson interviewed several community managers at our most recent
meet-up. There were three questions:

1. What, if anything, gets you excited about your job?
2. How did your life experience before Stack Exchange prepare you for
   this role?
3. What is your favorite site?

We're running these interviews for the summer (or winter, if you are
in the southern hemisphere) and we'll be back to the regular format
around August.

#### What do you think?

[Take a listen](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/catija.mp3) and respond in the answers below.

Comment: Slack ping at 13...

Comment: Does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i0M5X73GYc) sound familiar?

Comment: @AnneDaunted Sounds about right... if a bit robotic.

Comment: "catija" being pronounced "catiya" is valid in German and Slovenian :D

Comment: @lucasgcb I always pronounced _Catija_ as _catiya_ to myself, when reading!

Comment: This is supremely quotable. E.g.: 11 min 35 secs: "The meta experience is inherent to who we are" -- Catija (slightly paraphrased)

Comment: And at 11 min 07 secs: *"Meta Stack Exchange is for me the epitome of what our network is. And what our community is."* -- Catija (to be very strict, also paraphrashed)

Comment: 05 min 29 secs:  *"Our site is one-to-one interaction between a person with a question and a person with an answer. And then that goes out broadly to everybody who cares to look at it. ... That is what we do."* -- Catija

Comment: @PeterMortensen I know it was a typo but I love the word "paraphrashed" [parafrashed] I'm gonna use that whenever someone mangles a quote or takes an expression out of context. Absolutely brilliant! :)

Comment: Congratulations with your first work anniversary! I loved your answers on the interview, great podcast episode.

Comment: Regarding the tangential short discussion about whether product recommendations are successful on the network (shortly after the 10 minute mark), Mi Yodeya has a product-recommendation tag with 830 questions. Around 83% of them have answers, and only 6% of them are closed, so I guess it can work in certain circumstances.

Comment: @lucasgcb Indeed... [Katya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katya) is also the standard diminutive for Yekatarina (Katherine) in Slavic languages!