# Where to ask about gadgets for shoes?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about anti-sliding (on ice at winter) gadget for boots.

Comment: Looking for a life hack perhaps?

Comment: @Laurel actually I was thinking about product recommendation.

Comment: Yeah, recommendation questions aren't really accepted here on the Stack Exchange network, with the narrow exceptions of software and hardware. See [Why are "shopping list" questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) for why.

Comment: I would avoid phrasing the question as a shopping recommendation. Is there a related or more general question that may be useful to you that is OK for SE? Example: how to prevent boots from sliding on ice under such and such conditions? This one can be answered not only by product links.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331248/unicorn-meta-zoo-6-interview-with-catija#comment1080900_331248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Lifehacks Stack Exchange: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/  . Make sure to follow their guidelines, for example see the Help Center: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic .

Answer (score 7):

While **broad** product recommendations are [not allowed](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/356/17365) on our site "**The Great Outdoors**" searching there for the term "[ice boots](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=ice%20boots)" returns 75 results and suggests these tags:

- [winter-walking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-walking) - 14 results - "Questions about walking in winter conditions."
- [crampons](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crampons) - 20 results - "Crampons can be used for ice climbing or winter walking on snow and ice."
- [microspikes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microspikes) - 2 results - 'Less robust than crampons and they lack the front- and side-facing teeth' [tag wiki not completed]

More complex searches are also possible: [[shoes] or [boots] and [ice] is:question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bshoes%5D%20or%20%5Bboots%5D%20and%20%5Bice%5D%20is%3Aquestion) - 2 hits. Just be certain to [mention existing questions](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/22721/28063) on other sites so there isn't duplication in the effort offering answers you've already received.