# Announcing the arrival of Valued Associate #679: Cesar Manara

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

We [mentioned last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312699/new-resources-for-our-stack-exchange-network) that we were looking to rev up on additional resources for the Stack Exchange network and this announcement is meant to support that claim.  Due to the increased growth of our network sites, we found ourselves needing additional humans to help coordinate our plans for improving and refreshing our community experiences.

Please join me in welcoming [Cesar Manara](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m) to our Stack Exchange Community manager team!

[image: Cesar Manara's Profile pic]

Cesar is a Theater grad who's been CMing in the Games Industry since 2013 and is also - not professionally - a Playwright.
When he's not at the computer, he enjoys watching plays, musicals, playing some board games (not Munchkin, ugh), reading (not only Stephen King!), some YA, Sci-fi and the occasional behavioral psychology.

He brings experience in managing multiple cultures and time-zones as well as a knowledge of Portuguese and human behavior.

...He also [LARPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_action_role-playing_game). Yes.

Cesar will be working directly with me, [Catija](https://stackexchange.com/users/3979517/catija), and [Nicolas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky) on the SE sites and the International Stack Overflow communities. If you have any questions you'd like to ask Cesar, please do so here. He's new to the network so he'll be experiencing our sites with fresh eyes. If you see him around, please say "hello", or even better, "olá."

Comment: Ok. I see we need to add an interview question: "Do you LARP?" Welcome Cesar!

Comment: Nice t-shirt ;-)

Comment: Welcome Cesar!  Scriptwriting is on-topic on Writing.SE -- just sayin'. :-)

Comment: can't find him in all the pictures - missing red circles :o) - welcome

Comment: Bem vindo e olá Cesar! :-)

Comment: Thanks all! Jon, I'm glad you didn't ask! :P @MonicaCellio oh yea, I have my eyes on that one :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio If César is going to scriptwrite in Portuguese, he could help us graduate [Portuguese.SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: @gmauch great!  We can work together.

Comment: ¡Hola, @CesarM, y disfruta del increíble universo de intercambio de pila!

Comment: Am I the only one who had to Google "larp" and "ventrue" while reading this?

Comment: @AndrewMyers: It probably means you're too old (you didn't LARP yourself) or too young (your kids haven't encountered LARP for you).  Or maybe you're just on the wrong continent — it's a term used in the USofA (at least on the west coast, probably the east too, and in the middle); I know not where else it is used.

Comment: Do you often say: 'Et tu brute'?.  Just kidding.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's used in the UK as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler great, and I had to Google "USofA".

Comment: _"we found ourselves needing additional humans"_ said the Morlock to his community-manager ;) i olá @CesarM!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [LARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHC_Accelerator_Research_Program). Means he likes to go collide some particles on his free time, what did you think it meant? Personally as a programmer, I mostly ARP and sometimes RARP. (A bunch of us go out in the forest dressed as MAC addresses and another bunch as IP numbers, then it is kind of like speed dating from there.)

Comment: @iLuvLogix Elves are getting harder to find these days thus we settled on humans.

Comment: "CMing" = community managing?

Comment: @SteveBennett Correct!

Comment: @jpmc26 It means they needed more people to do the job of community manager.

Comment: @AndreSilva obrigado! :)

Happy to be the new human on the team here - and I'm sorry if the LARP word confused some of you, glad it got clarified already haha.

And I *definitely* hope not to get stabbed by multiple Brutus on the web.

Comment: Oi Cesar, bem-vindo à rede! Te esperamos na sala dos moderadores do [pt.so] :)

Comment: "He brings experience in managing multiple cultures and time-zones as well as a knowledge of Portuguese and human behavior. " LOL

Comment: Welcome!
What do you find harder, coding or acting? :o

Comment: @CristianUrrutia now that he posted an answer, you can post the comment there and delete it here. :)

Comment: Looking at the image on the t-shirt in the first photo, if you could be in a Hogwart's house, which would it be and why?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: frankly, if I ever encounter one I'm going to do just that. I mean, you're going to go anyways, so you might as well go big! :-)

Comment: "Valued Associate"... is that... management speak?

Comment: @SSight3 "Valued associate" is an ongoing term we've used internally to refer to many CMs when announcing their arrival to the network.  It is neither derogatory nor flattering, simply a term we've become endeared with.

Comment: It simply sounds like a honorific term for employee

Comment: Actually it's an old tradition on SE dating back to Jeff. And I'm pretty sure every early employee announcement referred to them as such

Comment: How is this recruitment done?

Comment: No more larping @CesarM?

Comment: @Luuklag just removing the picture - trying to consistently only use one picture publicly.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I just want to say thanks for the warm welcome, everyone! Do expect me to show up around some meta sites, sites proper and some chats as I get acquainted with everything - but please give some time before we take off the training wheels. :)

In the coming days, and probably weeks, I'll be immersing myself on all things exchange - that said, feel free to reach out if you see me around or tag me in stuff!

All the best!

[image: Card saying "Thanks! You're awesome. (Like this unicorn.)" with an arrow pointing down to a frolicking unicorn.]

Comment: Just out of interest, is it a paid position you now have or are you a volunteer of some sort?

Comment: @SyntaxError Community managers are employees of SE.

Comment: Parabéns Cesar! :)

Comment: Cheers Cesar from Manila all Power !

Comment: Olà Cesar ! : )

Comment: Olà Cesar, please pop into worldbuilding, as a weird offshoot of writing, we might just prove to be of interest to you.

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck I do read some questions there occasionally and you definitely have some super interesting, sometimes weird things going!

Answer (score 50):

Welcome, Cesar!

You're both a new user here and an experienced community manager elsewhere, a rare combination.  Will you consider sharing some of your experiences, impressions, and ideas for community growth as you learn your way around the SE network and its many different communities?  I don't necessarily mean all in one place; some things might work better in blog posts, on per-site metas, or in casual conversation in sites' chat rooms.  This seems like a great opportunity to talk with people in our communities so we can learn from each other.

Comment: Absolutely! I will definitely be hanging around, talking and writing more as time goes by and I get more familiar with everything. Hopefully, I'll be able to help the network and specific sites too!

Answer (score 27):

Hail, Cesar!

Since it's unclear from the description here: do you code? Will those of us who inhabit Stack Overflow and the other computery Stack Exchanges be seeing you around, or are you going to be focused on the other sites?

Comment: @AskQuestionWizard Aaaaah! A user named after [an abomination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381813/1709587)! Why do you exist!? Stay away from me, vile thing! (Also, thanks for the useful info.)

Comment: Like it was publicly found on my Linkedin - I know only the basics. I did do 2 years of a CS bachelor but then swapped to Theater and finished 5 years in that instead. Though I did dabble on Cpnael, php and most front-end related stuff for funsies.

Comment: @CesarM what?! No jQuery?! :-D

Comment: Actually never meddled with jQuery to be honest :c

Comment: @CesarM In case you're wondering why you're being asked about jQuery, go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/200582 and CTRL-F for `jquery` to learn a bit of historical trivia about Stack Overflow's culture. :)

Comment: No jQuery? Most of the memes on Stackoverflow are about jQuery, were you not asked questions about the memes during interviews? What, no!

Answer (score 24):

Congratulations on your new role, Cesar! I'm really excited to see how you help Stack Exchange grow and develop. I can tell already that you'll love this place and make a great addition to the community team. Good luck!

[image: Card with unicorn saying "I believe in YOU"]

Comment: Hah, cute pic =D

Comment: Love the picture! Thanks :D

Comment: No problem, @CesarM. Just getting you into [the unicorn-filled spirit of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicorns). (though I must admit this unicorn is cuter than most others I've seen.)

Comment: That horse appears to have been cross-bred with a flounder and has an ice-cream cone on its head.

Answer (score 18):

Welcome Cesar, and may that smile always stay on your face! :)

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the network Cesar M.
As you are based somewhere, likely have been to some other places, you will be able to join in at [Travel Stack Exchange.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

If you have traveled or will travel you are even more welcome.

And as a chat user, may I point out that several of our sites have great chats, where you can meet the people and often ask questions that do not fit on the sites.

Comment: Flagged as spam :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor, you are just jealous you did not get a personal invite back when,... but you are still welcome without one.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome Cesar!

As a member of [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), I'm glad to have a Portuguese-speaker CM!

Coincidence or not, a few days ago there was a comment in our meta [saying exactly how we miss CM's who are fluent in our language](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7719#comment29792_7719), as this would help breaking the language/culture-related barriers between our community and Stack Exchange itself.

I can't wait to see you participating in [our meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com).
*Nos vemos por lá*!

Answer (score 5):

*Salve, Cesar!*

(Welcome in Latin, which might be of your interest, based on T-shirt)

Answer (score 4):

Since everybody has already welcomed you, how about *please, take a seat* ;-]

Answer (score 3):

## Welcome Cesar

Yes, I know I'm late to this particular party.

[image: donuts]

Comment: Excessively fashionably