# Has a CM (specifically) gone back to being a mod before?

Tags: support, moderators, community-managers

I know that some Stack Exchange site moderators have become Stack Exchange employees and then later left the company and gone back to being moderators on their individual sites. Sklivvz and Jeremy Banks spring to mind (although both of those are no longer moderators); probably there are others too. But those two both had dev roles in the company, not working as Community Managers. Other former CMs, such as Aarthi and rchern, were never (as far as I know; all before my time) site moderators, so didn't retain any diamonds after leaving the company.

It's going to be strange to see [Jon Ericson, who's worked as a CM aka "super mod" for several years, acting once again as a normal site moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/278659). Less strange for former SE devs who didn't interact much with the community as part of their job for the company.

I wonder if this has happened before? **Has any CM (specifically a CM, not other types of SE employee) left their SE job but retained their former moderator diamond?**

Comment: Does it matter? There's a first time for everything. Not especially interesting. Jon will (once again) make an excellent moderator. I can't think of a better first time.

Comment: @CodyGray If you find the question uninteresting, feel free to ignore it. This is not a comment on anyone's suitability for any role, merely a piece of trivia that I'm curious about.

Comment: Related: [How exactly does the moderator inactivity process interact with employment at SE and employee moderator rights?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340658/how-exactly-does-the-moderator-inactivity-process-interact-with-employment-at-se) (contains an official response stating that moderators who become SE employees must resign as mods as a condition of their employment), and [follow-up question asking why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340713/why-are-moderators-who-become-stack-exchange-employees-required-to-resign-as-mod).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, this has not happened yet as of the time this answer was originally posted: until Jon Ericson, all former Community Managers who ceased to be employed at the company also ceased to be moderators after leaving.

Here are the CMs, past and present, ordered by period of service. This list does not count members of the support team as part of the group of CMs, although the answer is the same even if you do (at time of writing). (Note: current employees [are not permitted to serve as volunteer moderators while employed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340713/377214), regardless of their job in the company.)

| Employee | Mod prior to hiring? | Currently employed? | Returned to moderator status? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Robert Cartaino | No | No ([2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/04/19/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/)–2020) | - |
| Rebecca Chernoff ("rchern") | Yes (Web Applications) | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/04/welcome-valued-associate-rebecca-chernoff/)–2013) | No |
| Shog9 | No | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/25/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/)–2020) | - |
| Dori | Yes (Apple) | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/25/welcome-valued-associate-dori-smith/)–2011) | No |
| HedgeMage | Yes (Parenting) | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/21/welcome-valued-associate-susan-stewart/)–2011) | No |
| Grace Note | Yes (Gaming) | Yes, but no longer a CM ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/10/welcome-valued-associate-grace-note/)–) | - |
| Aarthi | No | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/15/welcome-chaos/)–2013) | - |
| Adam Lear | Yes (Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, Literature) | Yes, but no longer a CM (2012-) | - |
| **Tim Post** | Yes (Webmasters, Stack Overflow) | No ([2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/05/31/welcome-tim-post-our-latest-community-manager/)–2020) | **Yes**, now retired |
| **Jon Ericson** | Yes (Biblical Hermeneutics) | No ([2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/08/09/please-welcome-jon-ericson-community-manager/)–2020) | **Yes**, now retired |
| Gabe | No | Yes, but no longer a CM ([2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/08/23/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager/)–) | - |
| Pops ("Popular Demand") | No | No ([2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/06/community-management-by-popular-demand-kevin-chang-joins-the-team/)–2017) | - |
| Ana | No | No ([2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/11/08/raised-on-the-net-please-welcome-ana-noemi-community-manager/)–2018) | - |
| jmac | Yes (Workplace) | No ([2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/07/23/please-welcome-jmac-community-manager-of-the-rising-sun/)–2017) | No |
| hairboat ("abby hairboat") | No | No ([2011](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/15/welcome-chaos/)–2021) | - |
| Nicolas Chabanovsky | No, but was founder of hashcode.ru which became ru.SO | No ([2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/11/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/)–2023) | - |
| JNat | Yes (Anime & Manga) | Yes ([2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/)–) | - |
| animuson | Yes (Stack Overflow) | Yes, but no longer a CM ([2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/22/jnat-and-animuson-workin-on-ur-problemz/)–) | - |
| Taryn ("bluefeet") | Yes (Stack Overflow) | No ([2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/06/15/pivoting-into-a-new-career-please-welcome-taryn-pratt-bluefooted-community-manager/)–2021) | No |
| Juan M | No | No ([2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/08/21/welcome-juan-garza-and-stack-overflow-en-espanol/)–2022) | - |
| Catija | Yes (Arts & Crafts, Interpersonal Skills) | No ([2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313086)–[2023](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)) | No |
| Cesar M | No | Yes ([2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326611)–) | - |
| Ayo | No | No ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360990)–2021) | - |
| Rosie | No | Yes ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361266)–) | - |
| Philippe | No | Yes (VP of Community) ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362476)–) | - |
| Slate | Yes (Puzzling, Literature) | Yes ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367910)–) | - |
| Charlotte | No | Yes ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367910/)–) | - |
| V2Blast | Yes (Role-Playing Games) | No ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369260)–[2023](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)) | [Unknown](/posts/comments/1317194) |
| SpencerG | No | Yes ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369260/294691)–) | - |
| Bella_Blue | No | Yes ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371344)–) | - |
| Salmon_of_Wisdom | No | No ([2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371344)–2023) | - |
| Berthold | No | Yes ([2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376784)–) | - |
| Dalmarus | No | Yes ([2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378862)–) | - |
| Emerson | No | Yes ([2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381310)–) | - |
| Sasha | No | Yes ([2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386887)–) | - |

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork! TIL that rchern was once a mod and that HedgeMage was once a CM. Also, regarding Tim Post, I think he's no longer technically a CM? And are you sure animuson was never one?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Tim is management, but he's management of the CM team, so I figured he counts. animuson was hired as a support specialist, along with JNat, and as far as I know he's never actually changed titles.

Comment: @Sonic I've looked at a lot of hiring blog posts in the past half hour, and while _technically_ true, Pops was called "Popular Demand" while CM for all of a few minutes, so I chose not to include it.

Comment: Someone remember if Oded was a CM ? as he used to interact a lot on MSE

Comment: @yagmoth - No, he was not; he was a developer.

Comment: `Gabe - no //
Was never a community moderator//
No longer a CM//` That doesn't make sense. If they were *never* a CM, then the following assertion "no longer a CM" is conflictual in meaning.

Comment: @V2Blast For every CM in this list who's been previously a moderator and ceased to be employed later, the column as to whether they continued as a moderator needs to be filled in. Do you plan on requesting to be reinstated as an RPG mod?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: I haven't decided yet. Feel free to fill it in as "No" for now – it can always be updated later if I do.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm inclined to not fill in "No" unless one's made the firm decision to not be reinstated or a significant time has passed since the ceasing of their employment. I've filled it in as "Unknown" with a link to your comment.

Comment: This list seems to be mostly sorted by date of joining, but for some reason hairboat is down in the 2014-2015 era despite joining in 2011.