# Are Philippe and Rosie doppelgängers?

Tags: discussion, support, sock-puppets, stack-exchange-team

Looking at the profile of [Sara Chipps ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/139284/sara-chipps) (our Director of community), something struck me as odd. She has recently posted, amongst others, two posts welcoming the latest additions to the CM team, [Philippe](https://stackexchange.com/users/11122832/philippe?tab=accounts) and [Rosie](https://stackexchange.com/users/20728780/rosie?tab=accounts).

[image]

Now it turns out they are both valued associate #843, so are they [doppelgängers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger) or should one of them have a separate associate number?

Comment: They share the paycheck ...

Comment: Off by one error? 

Comment: I think you're jumping to conclusions. Maybe they just occupy the same physical space because they are unbound by the laws of mortal physics. How do you differentiate this being? Well you just give it the same number.

Comment: Obviously, one has employee number `843` and the other `843:`. It's an `NVARCHAR` field after all ...

Comment: Random number generator just gave same number again.

Comment: @Glorfindel curious what `"843:"++;` will return ...

Comment: And why aren't we welcoming the other 23 Valued Associates recruited since [Shodipo (#820)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360990/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-820-shodipo-ayomide) was recruited?

Comment: @Snow that were just associates ...

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about...

Comment: I thought you were doing nothing @Catija ;)

Comment: @Catija what should we give Valued Associate #1000 when they arrive?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating only #1024 is worth celebrating.

Comment: That is what 'union membership' means:)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ollie. I was to consumed thinking about [chips](https://www.google.com/search?q=chips&newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=ALeKk00KmzeS47ifeTNn614Jwvsx2f3wRA:1616615381657&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx_r7M2cnvAhUP_aQKHYVHBtQQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=902)

Comment: @RobertColumbia what is your reasoning for adding that tag?

Comment: @luuklag because the OP's implication was that these two users could possibly map back to the same person.

Comment: 843 is just a _really_ low value of 861. I can't believe y'all didn't know this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Phillipe now has a new number:

[Please join me in welcoming Valued Associate #861 Philippe Beaudette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362476/please-join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-861-philippe-beaudette?rq=1)

I guess this was just a copy/paste error.

Although this does result in 40 unwelcomed associates since [Shodipo (#820)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360990/join-me-in-welcoming-valued-associate-820-shodipo-ayomide) was recruited.

Comment: Or an 'off-by-18' error

Comment: I, for one, am glad to see this fixed.  I like Rosie and all, but I wasn't anxious to share the paycheck.

Comment: @Philippe someday, with four Guinea Pigs, you're certain to be sharing your paycheck again; and replacing electrical wiring.

Comment: @Rob when it's time to replace electrical wiring due to Guinea Pigs, it might be time to replace the Guinea Pigs for un-roasted versions of themselves as well.

Comment: @Luuklag, Guinea Pigs can strip several inches of power cord without getting electrocuted or causing a short circuit; until **you** touch something (usually a table lamp, because they move a little), then comes the flash and circuit breaker. --- Stripping power cords is one of their several skills.

Comment: Good thing I always kept mine in their cage @Rob

Comment: @Rob, i'm with Luuklag on this one.  Mine stay in their cage, unless we're doing lap time, in which case I am keeping a close eye on them.  But then I also live on the 22nd floor, and if they go on the balcony, they're going to have a very bad time.

Comment: @Philippe, [Guinea pigs in The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8801556#8801556).