# Is there any publicly available record since 2022 of Prashanth chatting with Meta Stack Exchange core community members?

Tags: support, ceo

### Main

This is a follow-up of some of my posts related to Meta Stack Exchange posts related to Prashanth's words.

During 2023 staff have brought the words of Prashanth, the Stack Overflow, Inc. CEO, to this community. Some have shared their perspective, but I haven't gotten comments and answers from someone representing the company. I understand that not all posts can be answered and commented on by staff; I am not complaining. This request asks to point to public records, such as posts here, a blog article, a podcast, or anything available on the Web to help humble users understand Stack Overflow's top management short and long-term vision about moderators, understanding them as users using the moderation privileges to keep communities healthy, useful and attractive to real-life subject matter experts.

### Related

- [What does Prashanth mean by "Community" in his blogposts, and how do the mods influence his perception of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389684/289691)

---

### Addendum (notes)

---

#### Prashanth vocabulary

I have identified that Prashanth has used the term "community" to refer to different concepts, sometimes to refer to a broad and abstract group, and other times to refer to the Stack Overflow community. It was mentioned have been communicating with community members. It's unclear if he is referring to someone belonging to the broad, abstract group who does not know about the conundrums of Stack Overflow and their sister communities or if he is referring to someone trusted by the core community of Meta Stack Exchange.

---

#### Offsite Staff communication with community members

I know that Stack Overflow staff sometimes contact users to interview them. I wonder if some of these interviews were led by or included Prashanth as an active participant and if there is a public record of such conversations. I'm particularly interested in knowing if Prashanth has conversed with someone with experience in moderation (upvote, downvote, flag, close to voting, review, etc.) and, more specifically, if that person is familiar with Meta Stack Exchange.

---

#### Related Staff created content

Philippe's answer to [Is SE [going to be] selling our content for AI model training? And what exactly does "reinvest back into our communities" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/289691) help to clarify some Prashanth words: Stack Overflow is doing things to ensure that the revenue that Stack Overflow / Stack Exchanges user-created content generates benefits content creators through investments in the corresponding communities. This is great, but it doesn't answer this specific question. I'm seeking help to find the source that makes Prashanth decide about the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange needs concerning keeping the communities, as mentioned above, healthy, useful and attractive to real-life subject matter experts.

Comment: _"I know that Stack Overflow staff sometimes contact users to interview them. I wonder if some of these interviews were led by or included Prashanth as an active participant and if there is a public record of such conversations."_ Having been in one of these conversations, I'm 99.9% sure the answer is __no__. It's just below his pay grade, for lack of a better description.

Comment: Also, this question is... Rambling. It's hard to follow. I suggest you cut down on the noise, to get to the point a little better...

Comment: very loosely related on the point of engagement (apparently more about engaging with company staff): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390555/997587 but definitely related on the point of vision for relationship with mods (unfortunately, it aged like milk).

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I'll undercut you here and say that did happen to me after I talked with Sara Chipps when she was still in her position, back in 2019.  This isn't in the cut-off that the OP wants so I declined to answer it.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Thanks for the comments. Regarding the question being Rambling, please excuse my poor communication skills and thank you for your patience. I will work on improving this question offsite and return later with an improved version.

Comment: No big progress yet; I want to share that I created a chatroom -> https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1718/.

Comment: It doesn't need ___more___ text. It needs to be cut down, the rambing needs to be reduced...

Comment: Aaron Hall (an SO mod) met with Prashanth, but that was 3 years ago. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393552/4014959