# Global community bulletin is down

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

The We Are Developers [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391338/1213814) is still featured, but the featured box has disappeared.

> [image: However, is still appears in]

It still appears in "Frequently Asked". Problem occurs on Chrome and Edge(if relevant). "Featured on meta" still works on other sites. UPDATE: the whole community bulletin is gone, including "Featured on Meta", "Hot Meta Posts", and the blog posts.

It looks like everything is back to normal now, have staff seen this post?

Comment: The "Featured on Meta" box on all sites also doesn't display the WeAreDevelopers meta post.

Comment: @lyxal is the "Featured on Meta" box only for specific site-meta posts or does it also include the posts on MSE?

Comment: The box is still there if there's per site featured posts or hot meta posts. There's also no SO blog post links

Comment: @lyxal looks like everything just dissapeared

Comment: More specifically: If a SE site has a [tag:featured] post on its meta or a meta post considered "hot", the yellow box will show that. Otherwise the box is missing. Sites with a box include Code Golf, Programming Language Design and Chess (which oddly enough contains only a SO blog post).

Comment: Seems broken for me too. I'd status-review this under normal circumstances ._.

Comment: ... actually it seems to be randomly coming up and down, which is extra fun

Comment: Looks like it's back on all sites now

Comment: @lyxal yeah, it's back, for now. If it happens sporadically, without staff even seeing it, it will most likely happen again.

Comment: And its gone again.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike You might wanna consider putting it under status-review, if it prevents visibility of Q/As about the strike, and only features marketing from SE.

Comment: Well, the MSE post about WeAreDevelopers has enough downvotes to signal that something's up, though...

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) I somehow got it as the *only* thing there on SO just for a moment, when it should actually also show [Preview of Search and Question-Asking Powered by GenAI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425766/11107541) and [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541).

[image]