What does the recent blog post mean by "community-driven AI"?
The title of this blog post is:

OverflowAI is now Generally Available! A new era of community-driven AI

I don't fully understand what it means by "community-driven AI". From a lot of the posts I have seen recently, the community doesn't really like this idea of integrating AI into SO, so why does the blog say it is "community-driven"?

Prashanth said "Community is the future of AI". But I still don't know what that's supposed to mean. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388401/new-blog-post-from-our-ceo-prashanth-community-is-the-future-of-ai/388404#comment1295071_388405

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_signifier

Marketing hype meant to make people feel like they have some impact on the AI.

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389684/what-does-prashanth-mean-by-community-in-his-blogposts-and-how-do-the-mods-in

It means buzzword bingo. There's no deeper meaning than repeating the words "AI" and "community" as many times as possible, pretending that you have a clue about what those two terms mean.

SO is supposedly very strong in community (not really) and AI is a hype currently (probably slightly overrated) so combining both would be the first instinct of every business manager from SO, even if maybe logically there is no direct connection. If anything AIs are data-driven and communities are common-interest groups but you can doubt that this community here values AI as much as the company currently. There is no community-driven AI.

I would advocate that if the AI was trained using "community generated data" then, in a way, it is "community driven". Technically speaking, nothing in that claim implies in any way that the community should be aware that their data id "driving" the LLM, that they are fine with that, that the "driving" meets all the local legal standard (I hope it does, wouldn't be surprised if it didn't) etc etc etc... I mean, it is not a lie, just Tolkien style Elvish tongue.

@SPArcheon community-generated-data-driven-AI would be possible with an emphasis on the AI as the main product. But it's not like we directly feed a community into the AI or create a community just for the AI to exist. Maybe some kind of inter-dependence was meant? Not sure which one though.


I don't fully understand what it means by "community-driven AI".

The community creates the data used by the AI. That's why "knowledge community" is also used, and this sentence is another hint at it:

Both humans and AI have a lot to offer, but not without their weaknesses. That’s where a community combined with the best of both comes in.


Kind of like Matrix where all humans are hooked up to machines in order to power the AI, yeah? The company's dream vision of a "community" for sure.

Just replace "driven" by "exploited" and it might make more sense. The interesting question: Is there a community left at the end.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Personally I'm only here for knowledge, and don't care about communities.
