# Please welcome Valued Associate #1065 - Bert!

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

Today, I’d like to welcome [Bert](https://stackexchange.com/users/24194181/berthold), who joined the community team last week as a new staff community manager. (The “staff” in his title is a description of his seniority…. Our CMs go from Associate CM, to Community Manager, to Senior CM, to Staff CM, to Principal CM.) Bert will be focusing on supporting Collectives on Stack Overflow, among other things, and he will report to me.

This is a fun one for me (actually, any opportunity to introduce new folks is fun for me, but this one is doubly so): I’ve worked with Bert before, so I know what we’re getting. Bert comes to us from his previous role as Director of Community for The Mighty (leading their health-focused community), but I worked with him before that, when we were teammates at Wikia/Fandom. At Fandom, Bert held a succession of roles, from being a community support manager to being the Director of Community Support and Engagement. He’s a talented community manager in his own right, and his skills as a product liaison are second to none, as I found out when working there. Bert is fascinated by the intersection of community, customer success, and product. Sounds about perfect for Collectives, right?

But more than all of that, Bert is just fundamentally a really nice guy. He’s the type of person that I want on our team, because he connects quickly and deeply with everyone he talks to, and he’s quickly a trusted, well-liked advisor.

I can’t tell you how excited I am to be working with Bert again, and to welcome him to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Network. Y’all make him feel welcome, please.

Comment: One traditional piece of information is missing from this post: Does @Bert have any pets? Maybe a cat, a dog or a tamagotchi?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have three dogs! One is the offspring of the other two. I've had cats in the past. Sadly, all my tamagotchis died in the late 90's.

Comment: @Berthold Lovely! Thanks for contributing this important piece of information! :)

Comment: Welcome @Berthold! The Teachers' Lounge has a bot which responds to `whois staff` with a list of Community Managers. So you're essentially a 'staff staff'?

Comment: not quite sure why the intersection of sponsored tags, leaderboards, and articles would necessitate needing a CM, but, congrats? welcome?

Comment: @Berthold are any of the dogs called [Ernie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernie_(Sesame_Street)), just for comedy value?

Comment: @Glorfindel It would seem so. I'm choosing to consider that an added layer of job security.

Comment: @KevinB To help guide that to becoming more than just the sum of its parts, in a community-first way. Thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: @motosubatsu Kudos for putting an Ernie question out there on day 1. I was worried it might be weeks before that happened! The answer is no, the comedy value of dog names is usually something more obscure (or at least less obvious). For example, a former (now passed on) dog was named Libby, after Parker Posey's character in "Waiting for Guffman". However, when she was pregnant with my younger sibling, my mother was constantly asked if it would be named Ernie.

Comment: I'm so excited that @Berthold is here. He's been such a joy to work with this past week and a half. I'm looking forward to getting to work with him more. And berthold since you quoted one of my favorite movies there ^ your stock just went up even higher in my book. :)

Comment: Welcome @Berthold :) We are so happy that you are here with us!

Answer (score 11):

### Welcome, Bert!

I'm glad the company is continuing to expand the Community Team by hiring more CMs, especially those with such extensive experience in community management. I'm looking forward to seeing what you bring to the team <s>and hearing whatever entertaining stories you can share with us about Philippe</s>!

Comment: awww crap.  Now I have to stop and think about what embarassing things I might have said or done while I was there....

Comment: 'All of it' seems a good answer 

Comment: I'd like to think that there might be a few minutes that weren't totally boneheaded but... now that I consider it.... yeah, probably @JourneymanGeek is right. :P

Answer (score 0):

> "he connects quickly and deeply with everyone he talks to"

In other words, he has mastered one of the most valuable and appreciated people skills of them all!

Welcome Bert!

P.S. I also appreciated your comment about tamagochis, as it makes me nostalgic for the 1990s :)