# Announcing the arrival of Valued Associate #1214: Dalmarus

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

We have been on a journey to revamp and improve the /contact support experience - it has moved back to the Community Team, we hired dedicated folks to do it, and switched systems more than once by now.

A couple of months ago, the support team moved from Rosie to me, and I wanted to make some further changes - furthermore, Slate is also changing her focus from support and moving back to Rosie’s team to work with them.

That’s where [Dalmarus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1189407/dalmarus) comes in! I’m incredibly excited to have hired him and for the future of our support experience, he brings a ton of support and community management experience and joins us from the gaming industry as a Senior Community Manager here at Stack.

Dalmarus has spent the last 11 years helping build and mold the communities and community programs of companies such as BioWare, ArenaNet, EA, and Facebook. For the 10 years before that, he did technical support in both the private and government sectors. As you can see, seeing an opportunity to combine his two career paths at Stack Overflow proved too tempting to pass up. ;)

In his free time, he enjoys playing video games with friends. Being an old EverQuest fan, MMORPGs are his main staples (RIP Vanguard: Saga of Heroes!). When not playing games, you can find him reading military science fiction or fantasy and waiting impatiently for the latest Rachel Morgan/The Hollows book to release.

He also loves spending time with his wife and their three pets - two dogs and one cat. Originally from the United States, they've spent the last two years in Germany and are hoping to move to Portugal sometime next year. He loves trying new food places, so be sure to send any recommendations his way!

Please join me in giving a warm welcome to Dalmarus! He has a lot of work ahead of him, but from what I’ve seen in the couple of weeks he’s been with us, I have no doubt he’ll be a ton of help in improving everyone’s experience with our support systems.

Comment: This is very cool; welcome @Dalmarus! On other topic: why hasn't there been an announcement that [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) has *returned to SE* in [May 2022](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/1523641670486704137)?!

Comment: Well the announcements generally tend to be for CMs these days, for various reasons

Comment: Is it just me, or does the term "Valued Associate" (with proper caps) bring up echoes of *1984* and *Paranoia* RPG?

Comment: @ZeissIkon: I'm just wondering about all the "Unvalued" Associates ಥ_ಥ

Comment: @ZeissIkon let's start feature request asking to change it to "Esteemed Brother", or "Esteemed Sister" instead. :D

Comment: Welcome, Valued Associate #1214. Welcome to Meta 17. You have chosen, or been chosen, to moderate one of our finest remaining StackExchange sites...

Comment: @V2Blast are there plans to feature Yaakov's post of today about cleaning up double votes?

Comment: @Luuklag Possibly – that's for another staff member to determine. But I did unfeature this partly to allow for that possibility :)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Thanks for the welcome, Cesar. I'm excited to be here and am looking forward to improving Community Support for everyone. :)

As requested, pictures of our little monsters... I mean pets ;)

[image: two chihuahuas, one white and one black]

[image: an orange cat]

Comment: Welcome!  Cesar mentioned you have pets—any pictures to share? ^_^

Comment: Oh wow, +500 just for the pets! :D

Comment: Chihuahuas. "monsters" is definitely appropriate ;)

Comment: It has been fantastic getting to know you Dalmarus over these past few weeks. We're so glad that you are here!

Comment: Adorable! They're very photogenic :)

Comment: Welcome and congrats!

Comment: Hate to be perhaps the only -1 here, but one downvote for each dog, then one upvote for the cat. Oh, and congrats, despite the doggies.

Comment: Omg they are soooooo cute <3

Answer (score 16):

> We have been on a journey to revamp and improve the /contact support experience - it has moved back to the Community Team, we hired dedicated folks to do it, and switched systems more than once by now.

Incidentally, does this mean that Grace and animuson are now under the Community Team (again)? They've always been in a bit of a gray space where they're sorta CM-like but not quite, and this change doesn't exactly clear that up.

Comment: No - ever since we hired CMs to handle it, Grace and Animuson are no longer handling the /contact tickets, it's all under the CM team now. Grace actually hasn't been handling them for sometime now.

Comment: Ah, cool. So what are those two handling these days? Teams support?

Comment: Yep! Teams' support is their job :)

Comment: You'll still see me pop up now and then since I also maintain the [public support portal](https://support.stackenterprise.co/) that both teams share. :) So if that breaks you can more than likely blame me.

Answer (score 10):

Welcome, Dalmarus! I know our Support team has definitely needed more, well, support – I'm glad you're on the team now! You definitely seem to have lots of experience in that field.

(We should play some games together sometime!)

Comment: Do the games include JQuery and/or waffles and syrup?